# What kind of error can I get when I have a executor request that either the memory or cpu cannot fit in a node

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes

What kind of error can I get when I have a executor request that either the memory or cpu cannot fit in a node?

Do I get the error from driver? Such as there is no resource available or I get the error from the scheduler which states that the request cannot fit in the cluster?

Comment: Generally, if there are resource constraints on the K8s setup for Spark executors, the following logs will be there, in Driver pod:

`[task-starvation-timer] Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources`

Comment: It is true. There can be multiple items can cause the "Initial job has not accepted any resources". For this thread, I am asking if spark/resource schema has some log to show that the requested memory/cpu cannot fit to any of the node. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that I have found the answer by myself.

If you request an executor with requested memory/cpu that cannot fit in any of the nodes, for example, your requested memory/cpu is greater than the node it has. The following error can be found in the scheduler log

If the requested the cpu core number is greater than the total cpu core number in the node, you will get similar error like below. Pay attention to the keyword **Insufficient cpu** in the log

```
I1115 18:02:02.371606      10 factory.go:339] "Unable to schedule pod; no fit; waiting" pod="dxxxs-xxxxx/xxxpycomputediffconnections3np-uoiqajbz-exec-1" err="0/433 nodes are available: 1 Insufficient cpu, 1 node(s) had taint {ToBeDeletedByClusterAutoscaler: 1668535262}, that the pod didn't tolerate, 431 node(s) didn't match Pod's node affinity/selector."
```

If the requested the memory is greater than the total memory in the node, you will get similar error like below. Pay attention to the keyword **Insufficient memory** in the log

```
I1115 18:02:02.371606      10 factory.go:339] "Unable to schedule pod; no fit; waiting" pod="dxxxs-xxxxx/xxxpycomputediffconnections3np-uoiqajbz-exec-1" err="0/433 nodes are available: 1 Insufficient memory, 1 node(s) had taint {ToBeDeletedByClusterAutoscaler: 1668535262}, that the pod didn't tolerate, 431 node(s) didn't match Pod's node affinity/selector."
```